# How to prevent browser password prompts when no Active Directory single-sign-on?

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, kerberos, google-chrome

We have single-sign-on working on an internal website, with Apache and `mod_auth_kerb` ... except users without the relevant browser config are getting password prompts instead of an error page.

Users who have tweaked their web browser config to allow the site get straight in. The problem is for users who haven't yet performed that browser configuration: we want them to see an error page, but instead Edge, Chrome, and IE all prompt for a username and password.

We have `KrbMethodK5Passwd off`. This has the desired effect on Firefox users, who see the error page.

How can we prevent the other browsers from prompting for a password when SSO fails? We don't want passwords going over the network, and we don't want to train users into thinking it's acceptable to supply their Windows username and password to websites.

Heres's Chrome's unwanted prompt:

[image: Chrome prompting ‘Sign in’ with a username and password for a site with an obscured URL ending in ‘.local’]

And here's Edge's (IE's is pretty much the same):

[image: A dialog box entitled ‘Windows Security: Microsoft Edge’ prompting for username and password for a domain]

If the user presses `Esc` 7 times then the prompt eventually goes away and the user gets to read the error page. But there's no reason a user would think to do that (if it didn't work the first 6 times, why try a 7th?), whereas they may try submitting their password.

The server's running Ubuntu, and has this Apache config enforcing the authentication:

```
<Location />
  AuthName "Internal Website Domain Authentication"
  AuthType Kerberos
  Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/HTTP.keytab
  KrbMethodNegotiate on
  KrbMethodK5Passwd off
  Require valid-user
  ErrorDocument 401 /error/authentication.html
</Location>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

to prevent password prompts you have to save it for the first time when you login the google asks to save it, after that whenever you login to the website you will be automatically redirected to the webpage.

Comment: Hi Marlin, The OP asks about a configuration on the server side to prevent a password dialogue to pop up, or a webbrowser configuration entry (probably set in an automated deployment process). What do you mean with 'the google'? When using ServerFault try to be as specific as possible when proposing an answer!

Comment: Hi, Marlin. Unfortunately in this case the user shouldn't *ever* enter any password: they are either enabled for single-sign-on (without a password), or should see the error message.